# Deploying Strapi on ubuntu server using Docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu, strapi

So I'm trying to deploy Strapi using docker on my ubuntu server with Nginx. I'm now just trying to get any strapi image up and running, but as you can see in the terminal image below it's just stuck on 'Opening the admin panel...' and I can't seem to access the admin panel regardless.

Does anyone know what might cause this? I'm running it using production mode.

[image]

Comment: Would you please add the steps used to run the app?

Comment: Can you try accessing http://127.0.0.1:9100/admin? Could you please add information what you see while accessing it in a browser?